# Checkout Android Project in Eclipse

Tags: android

For some reason whenever I checkout my Android project from the SVN repository into Eclipse it fails to recognize that it is an Android project.

Even when I use "Convert to Android Project" it says: "Project1 does not exist."

What might be the problem or how do I checkout an android project from a repository?

Comment: this question was originally asked about http://replicaisland.net/

Answer (score 2):

Solution::

Open the  .project file inside your project folder

add
1) inside `<buildSpec>` add `<name>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder</name>`

```
  <buildSpec>
     ...
     ...
     ...
 <buildCommand>
```

org.eclipse.jdt.core.javabuilder

2) inside `<natures>` add `<nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>`

```
<natures>
          ...
           <nature>org.eclipse.jdt.core.javanature</nature>
 </natures>
```

3)go to Properties -> Java Build Path -> Source -> add folder replicaisland/gen

**Update: this question was originally asked about http://replicaisland.net/**

Comment: can you tell me a link to the steps required to checking out and checking in projects for android in eclipse? What to Export and what not too, im confused. Because many times I deleted a file, export the project, reimport, and the file is back! Why?

Comment: hi Vass what file are you tryin to delete, a resource file, class, files inside "Gen" folder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9788467/410975 http://stackoverflow.com/q/9559932/410975 are links to two questions that I really haven't really got working. Essentially substituting SVN style with dropbox. All sorts of problems occur now. I have tried testing via making separate workspaces on the same machine and exporting importing between them to a common external folder and now application don't show up any more in the AVD. I cannot delete a java file then export and not find it pop up again on the next import etc :( so Im not just starting the SVN trail to do this stuff now, :/