# With Eclipse, errors in trying to Import previously Exported Android project, reports a workspace conflict

Tags: android, eclipse, import, synchronization, dropbox

I am using Eclipse for Android. I had a fresh/clean new workspace created. I had a folder where a pre-existing Android project was exported to from Eclipse. I open Eclipse from using this new workspace and do `Import` > `Existing Projects into Workspace` > *I select the project folder which is a previous export* > `Finish`. 
All is great with this importing, as the files are all there and the directory structure is as it should be.

Then after some edits I do `Export` > `General - File System` > *I select the same directory folder I imported from with the selected option to overwrite existing files without warning*. Then I restart Eclipse and try to import the exported project in the same way but it says **Some projects cannot be imported because they already exist in the workspace**.

The whole point of this is to be able to synchronise an Android project by using a dropbox folder to be shared. That different computers can access the exported project in a common/shared folder work with it and then modify contents. It seems that with Eclipse the usual way is for an SVN to be used instead but is it not possible with a shared folder? I am struggling to find a process to import make changes and export again and on importing again for those changes made to be preserved if they were not made from the same Eclipse session.

Comment: I think a cvs, such as SVN, is a common solution when a project has several contributors. It allows for rollbacks, branches, merges etc. Under Windows using an integrated SVN client such as Tortoise SVN spares one from learning SVN commands. Seems there's no reason not to use SVN and using SVN (or other cvs) is often required by the shops. Perhaps you might want to try.

Comment: @Alex, so it seems that since most go by the SVN solution, problems using different routes are considered redundant and not given attention and difficult to get out of? And taking the common path of an SVN would solve things alot more easily than me trying to figure out how to do this with a tool not made for this purpose?

Comment: No, I just wanted to comment that SVN is nice.

Comment: @Alex, is using SVN straightforward? Easy to do the simple task of synchronize an Android project between a couple of computers? Will these difficulties I am encountering with Dropbox not exist? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to get the error from appearing is to initially have my workspace folder in a separate directory/folder from the project space which was defined later in the non-default location which is with the workspace. Then importing does not conflict with what is automatically loaded with the workspace folder.